# KDP question, same book different ISBN

Tags: kdp

I'm planning to publish my books to lulu but the problem is ISBN.
I know that I can't use the same Isbn, so my question is:
can I publish the same book and same title to other book stores with a different ISBN?

Have you any direct experience?

Comment: Surely for the same book it should be the same ISBN